# Find and group duplicates

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hopefully I'm able to explain what I'm trying to achieve, it's a bit complicated I think.

I have two tables like this:

```
ID   | Names
--------------
A    | Name1
B    | Name2
C    | Name3

ID   | md5s
--------------
A    | a
A    | b
B    | c
C    | a
C    | c
```

I'm trying to achieve this: In the end I want to have a list of all "Names" that have duplicate MD5  values and in which other "Names" these MD5 values were found.

So I want to get something like this:

Name1 has 5 duplicate entries in "md5s" with Name8, 4 with Name10 ...

I need a list for all "Names" like described above.

Hopefully that makes sense to someone. :)

I already tried it with this SQL statement:

```
SELECT names,COUNT(names) AS Num FROM tablename GROUP BY names HAVING(Num > 1);
```

But that gives me only the md5s that are duplicates. The relation to the rest is totally missing.

*edit:fixed typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like there must be a better solution than this, but here's what I've thrown together for you:

```
SELECT  a.names NAME,
        b.names DUPE_NAME,
        COUNT(*) NUM_DUPES
FROM    names_tbl a, names_tbl b, md5_tbl md5a, md5_tbl md5b
WHERE   a.id < b.id
AND     a.id = md5a.id
AND     b.id = md5b.id
AND     md5a.md5 = md5b.md5
GROUP BY a.names, b.names
ORDER BY a.names
```

The rule of thumb with finding duplicates is that you probably need to do a self join. This would be simpler if the names and their associated md5's were in the same record, but because they're in separate tables I think you need two versions of each table.

Comment: Hi David, great this seems to work, thank you. There is only one last "problem". Each "Resultgroup" appears two times. In the end we have A - B = 11 and B - A = 11. Is there any possibility to fix this with SQL or do i have to handle this in my script?

Comment: Hi Andy, fixed the script. Instead of joining where the a.id <> b.id, I modified it to a.id < b.id so it will only return one record for each matched pair. Let me know if you have any other questions.